# Different task running at the same time on a C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm a industrial engeneering student and I have in mind a pretty cool application using ROS. I know that this is not an specific forum about ROS, but as I am programming in C++ and the question is more related to C++ than ROS, I believe that this is a very good place to ask my question.

My problem is that I have a ROS node that must do three different task. These three tasks are equally important so it must be run at the same time. I'm not newer in C++ programming but I've never worked with this kind of problems. I've made a little researh through the internet about 
multi-threading and parallel programming and I still don't know the difference between each other.

1. - Which are the differences between multi-threading and parallel programming?
2. - Which might be the best option for the C++ program?
3. - How can I implement these methods on a C++ program?
4. - Is there any guide for people who are getting started with this topic?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For 1) it may depend on context. MPI is parallel programming, but not necessarily multi-threaded.

Comment: It seems you can use any standard C++ threads/async calls with ROS as explained [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/215266/how-implement-a-multi-threaded-ros-node-with-callbacks-not-being-subscribers/), as long as you adhere to the overall [ROS concepts](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts).

Comment: Thanks you for the information and links!

Comment: Re, "...tasks are equally important so...must be run at the same time." I don't know what ROS is, but why must "equally important" tasks be performed concurrently? What bad thing would happen if they were performed one after the other?

Comment: If they performed one after the other I can miss data. In order to improve the security of my robot, I must assure for my application that no data is lost,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-threading describes the concept of having multiple tasks running in parallel for one single program.

Parallel programming is using one parallel concept (might be multi-threading) in your code.

Your questions 2 can not be answered since one uses the other.

A good guide on how to use parallel programming to improve the performance of your code can be found [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/)

Answer (score 0):

"Parallelism" or "parallel computing" refers to any technique that exploits the resources of computing hardware that is capable of doing more things at the same time than a traditional, single-CPU computer can do. It's a broad topic, that covers everything from modern multi-CPU desktop, server, and mobile platforms to [GPU programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) to esoteric things like [systolic array processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_array) and [connection machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_Machine) that have not yet escaped from their university laboratories.

"Multi-threading" is one of several popular techniques that extend the capabilities of a conventional procedural programming language to let us have multiple different activities to happen *[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing)* within a single process.  Parallelism is a subset of concurrency. Any activities that are able to happen concurrently within a single process potentially can happen in parallel if you have the right hardware and operating system.

> How can I implement these methods on a C++ program?

Use the [threading features in the standard C++ library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a lot!